# Guardar nombre de archivos en arreglo

Tags: c#

Estoy obteniendo la ruta del folder donde se encontraran varios archivos, después leo los archivos y como ultimo necesito guardar los nombres en una arreglo..como hago eso?

```
   //ruta del folder
   string folder_save = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["folder"]; 

   /*leer todos los archivos del folder*/
   string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folder_save);
   string[] name_folder;
      //guardar en arreglo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias usar

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folder_save);
string[] name_folder = files.Select(x=>Path.GetFileName(x)).ToArray();
```

asi estarias usando linq para obtener los nombre de los archivos

Comment: podrias explicarme la segunda linea, porfavor.

Comment: cual parte? la del Select() es un metodo de extension de linq que usa lambda por eso el =>